# Javascript: Initializing a variable from a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, google-maps, variables

I am working in Google Maps and have three+ tile overlays to create.  An example:

**Tile Overlay**

```
var parkingOptions = {                     //Parking Overlay
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
        return "/maps/tiles/tilesparking/" + zoom + "_" + coord.x + "_" + coord.y + ".png";
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
};

var parkingMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(parkingOptions);
```

However, to avoid 404 errors by missing tiles outside of my mapping range, my code is a little more complex; thus, I intended to make a loop where a specific keyword assigned to each overlay *(here given as "parking")* would be inserted into the above code.  Thus:

**For Loop**

```
var tileNames = ["base", "parking", "access"];

for (var i = 0; i < tileNames.length; i++) {
    //insert Tile Overlay code here
};
```

However, I have one particular issue: I can not find a way to take the string from the tileNames array and use them in initializing the two variables in the Tile Overlay code.  Ideally, I would like to achieve something like this:

**Attempt 1**

```
var tileNames[1] + "Options" = {  //ideally: var parkingOptions = {
    //insert remaining code
};
```

However this doesn't work, nor did I really expect it to.  Neither would trying to create those full strings and trying to insert it into the initialization:

**Attempt 2**

```
var newOptions = tileNames[1] + "Options";
var newOptions = {
    //insert remaining code
};
```

Thus, is there a way to do place a string into initializing variables?

---

**Note:** I have included my own alternative solution to the problem as an answer.  It should work, but it destroys the names of the variables and replaces it with a nondescript array variable.  I preferably would like to retain a descriptive variable name as they are used often in adding and hiding the overlays in the resulting code.

---

**Solution** *For this question anyways...*

```
var tileNames = ["beloit", "parking", "access"];
var mapType = {};

for (var i = 0; i < tileNames.length; i++) {
    var tileOptions = {
        getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
            return "/maps/tiles/tiles" + tileNames[i] + "/" + zoom + "_" + coord.x + "_" + coord.y + ".png";
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
    };
    mapType[tileNames[i]] = new google.maps.ImageMapType(tileOptions);
};
```

The other part of the puzzle, the "tileNames[i]" in the getTileUrl function is undefined because the function wants it when it is executed rather than placing the name string into the function; however, that is a new question to be found here: [Javascript: Making a variable static when defining a function in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214807/javascript-using-a-string-to-define-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't do this:

```
var tileNames[1] + "Options" = {
  //insert remaining code
};
```

but you can do this:

```
window['a'] = 'b';
alert(a); // shows 'b'
```

or if you are in a function

```
this['a'] = 'b';
```

EDIT:

```
var obj = {};
obj.a = 'a';
// obj.a == obj['a']
alert(obj['a']) // alerts a
```

Comment: Are those associative arrays, or some kind of notation?  I was under the impression that Javascript doesn't explicitly support associative arrays:  [link](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays)

Comment: that is a object (associative arrays are objects), object.a == object['a']

Answer (score 1):

Now, I don't know if the above is indeed possible *(and I would somewhat prefer it did as I'll explain below)*, but in drafting this question, the various other Q/A I read beforehand began to make more sense.  Their general message: "use arrays":

**Possible Solution**
*(Edited; should be usable now.)*

```
var tileNames = ["beloit", "parking", "access"];  //Would be used more than once.
var tileMapType = [];

for (var i = 0; i < tileNames.length; i++) {
    var tileOptions = {
        getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
            return "/maps/tiles/tiles"+tileNames[i]+"/" + zoom + "_" + coord.x + "_" + coord.y + ".png";
        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
    };
    tileMapType[i] = new google.maps.ImageMapType(tileOptions);
};
```

The only issue with this approach is that, in the code which follows, I have to place these MapTypes into the map as well as toggle them as visible and invisible, and using the nondescript tileMapType[x] to do so hinders overall readability.  *(Perhaps this doesn't matter as much as I think it does, but still. >.>)*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've understood your question, you can encapsulate your tiles in an object and refer to the layer by the name you provide:

```
var tileNames = ["base", "parking", "access"];
var Tiles = {};

for (var i = 0; i < tileNames.length; i++) {
    Tiles[tileNames[i]] = makeOverlay(tileNames[i], coords, zoom);
};

//iterate the maps
for (var tile in Tiles)
   alert(Tiles[tile].someGoogleMapPropery)

//individually     
alert (Tiles.base.someGoogleMapPropery)
alert (Tiles.parking.someGoogleMapPropery)
//or
alert (Tiles["access"].someGoogleMapPropery)


function makeOverlay(name, coords, zoom) {
    return new google.maps.ImageMapType({
            getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
                return "/maps/tiles/tiles" + name + "/" + zoom + "_" + coord.x + "_" + coord.y + ".png";
            },
            tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
        });
}​
```

Comment: Many thanks for this answer as well.  I was playing around with objects when your example made cuzzea's intent clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to read variables like that using eval(), but not set them.

Example:

var a = "b";
var b = "c";
eval (a); // returns "c"

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm looking to set them.  Also, what part are you referring to with "read variables like that"?

Comment: It's possible to read variables using the content of another variable as the name. (i.e. variable x contains the name of the variable I'm actually trying to read).

Comment: I think I see what you're getting at:
`b = new google.maps ; baseMapType = b ; eval(baseMapType)`.  No?  We still have the issue of naming "baseMapType" from the tileNames array, namely something like `tileNames[0] + "MapType // should read 'baseMapType'`