# Javascript: Making a variable static when defining a function in a loop?

Tags: javascript, string, function, google-maps, variables

Working with Google Maps, I have the following code:

```
var tileNames = ["base", "parking", "access"];
var mapType = {};

for (var i = 0; i < tileNames.length; i++) {
    var tileOptions = {
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
        return "/maps/tiles/tiles" + tileNames[i] + "/" + zoom + "_" + coord.x + "_" + coord.y + ".png";
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
    };
mapType[tileNames[i]] = new google.maps.ImageMapType(tileOptions);
};
```

Here is my issue: the "tileNames[i]" in the "getTileUrl" function is undefined when the function is executed.  However, the "tileNames" array is only meant to be used here in defining the "mapType" object and thus, unlike the "coord" and "zoom" variables which are passed to the function, I'm looking to use "tileNames[i]" to define that part of the function.  Thus, ideally, the function assigned to mapType.parking would look like this...

```
function(coord, zoom) {
    return "/maps/tiles/tilesparking/" + zoom + "_" + coord.x + "_" + coord.y + ".png";
};
```

...after the function is defined in the first piece of code.  Is there any way to take the value of a variable/array and use it to statically define a function while maintaining the other two variables as variables.

---

**Edit:** Looking at the various answers below, the following is the best I've been able to achieve thus far.  While bind might be the ideal approach in a more general scenario, in this specific case, "getTileUrl:" apparently wants a specific syntax and placing the bind around the function defined for it causes errors for Maps.  In trying KGZM's suggestion, it works in everything up to date and not in IE8 and below.

```
var tileNames = ["beloit", "parking", "access_p"];
var mapType = {};

for (var i = 0; i <= (tileNames.length - 1); i++) {
    (function(i) {
        tileOptions = {
            getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
                return "/maps/tiles/tiles" + tileNames[i] + "/" + zoom + "_" + coord.x + "_" + coord.y + ".png";
            },
            tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
        };
        mapType[tileNames[i]] = new google.maps.ImageMapType(tileOptions);
    })(i);
};
```

Comment: This is an issue of scope. Defining functions in a loop tends to lend itself to this mistake. Define your function outside of the loop, and pass in the index as flynfish suggested.

Comment: @JoeTuskan, this is a late response, but the reason he can't pass the index as a parameter is because the Google Maps API has defined the arguments for these functions for him, that's why I suggested ``bind`` below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a functional programming concept that can handle this well

Basically, your function actually has three arguments, the `zoom` variable, the `coord` object, and the `tileNames[i]` value, but you want the `tileNames[i]` value to be fixed to a particular value at one time in your code, and leave the other two variables as actually variable.

```
function getTileUrlBuilder(tilename) {
    return function(coord, zoom) {
        return "/maps/tiles/tile" + tilename + "/" + zoom + "_" + coord.x + "_" + coord.y;
    };
}
```

Then you can use this function in your loop. However, since this is actually a common operation, you can use the `bind` method to handle this:

```
(function(tilename, coord, zoom) {
    return "/maps/tiles/tile" + tilename + "/" + zoom + "_" + coord.x + "_" + coord.y
}).bind(this, tileNames[i]);
```

That will "bind" the implicit `this` to the current `this`, and then bind the first argument to the current value of `tileNames[i]`.

EDIT: This, I think, should be the working code.

```
var tileNames = ["beloit", "parking", "access_p"];
var mapType = {};

function getTileUrlFull(tileName, coord, zoom) {
    return "/maps2/tiles/tiles" + tileName + "/" + zoom + "_" + coord.x + "_" + coord.y + ".png"
}

for(var i = 0; i < tileNames.length; i++) {
    mapType[tileNames[i]] = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: getTileUrlFull.bind(this, tileNames[i]),
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
    });
}
```

Comment: @JoeTuskan, I forget about those incompatibilities. Just use an ES5 shim or implement the relatively trivial ``bind`` method yourself for that.

Comment: Very true have a vote. There's a shim here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: @JoeTuskan, I just use this ES5 shim collection: https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim There are listed caveats, but most of them are along the lines of: "If you intentionally try to misuse the API in ways that don't work in ES5, weird things will happen." Which I'm fine with.

Comment: This undoubtably seems to be the thing I have been looking for and- in any general case- it would be the solution.  Yet, in my haste, I did not realize that this method appears unusable in my specific case as my testing tells me that the function which must be defined after `getTileUrl:` must reference both `coord` and `zoom`, with an unused 3rd parameter which is some object _(ie. I can't pass i along)_.  Likewise, trying to enclose the function in the `bind` also throws errors from Maps.  I'll add what I have to the question here shortly.

Comment: What's the error you're getting, exactly? I don't see why ``bind`` wouldn't work, so long as ``bind`` is actually defined in your JS environment.

Comment: I don't recall; it was likely just my misuse of `bind` which was causing the errors.  In using your new code block, I arrive at the same point I had with KGZM's suggestion, namely it works in all but IE8 and below. To use the ES5 shim, I assume I simply have to reference it in my HTML and then edit the function call to read `getTileUrlFull.prototype.bind(this, tileNames[i]),`, no?  I've tried this, but all browsers return `getTileUrlFull.prototype.bind is not a function`.

Comment: @TerraFimeira, no, you don't need to call the prototype. Once you add the shim, it will be defined for all functions (assuming the shim is loaded and executed before your code is).

Comment: Working now, many thanks.  One last question, is it safe to have all of these functions/features redefined by the shim if I have no _(direct)_ need for them to be, or is there little risk in having the entire ES5 shim enabled?

Comment: There is essentially no risk in new code. If you don't call them, they won't do anything. If it's legacy code, you need to make sure that nothing in your code is using any of the method names new to ES5, but that should be done anyways to work better on more modern browsers (and not mess with third party scripts that expect the standard behavior).

Answer (score 2):

You need another closure. After your loop runs the value of variable 'i' is 3. tileNames[3] => undefined. But every function you're creating contains a reference to the same i variable.

Try something like this:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < tileNames.length; i++) {
      (function(i) {
        //loop body goes here.
      })(i);
    };
```

Comment: What exactly is this?  It works for the most part, but seemingly not in IE9.  Is this a `bind` as Davis Ellis suggested, or something else?

Comment: @TerraFimeira, it's a closure constructor. Each run through the loop produces a *new* ``i`` variable with a fixed value, rather than referencing the outer ``i`` variable (that is equal to ``tileNames.length`` at the end of the loop).

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `i` into your `getTileUrl` function:

```
getTileUrl: function(i, coord, zoom) {
        return "/maps/tiles/tiles" + tileNames[i] + "/" + zoom + "_" + coord.x + "_" + coord.y + ".png";
    },
```